# How do I use a variable to find an element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, user-input

I'd like to take some user input and use it to find a certain object in an array. But when I try to do it with the code below, I get an undefined error. What am I doing wrong?

```
function findNextLevel() {
    var currentLevel = parseFloat(document.getElementById("currentLevel").value);
    var xpForLevel = trainerLevels.currentLevel;
    document.getElementById("result01").innerHTML = xpForLevel;
}
```

Comment: If you are using a variable to get the value of a property, you have to use the bracket notation: `var xpForLevel = trainerLevels[currentLevel];`

Comment: And the problem is revelaed, it was so simple. Thanks

Comment: Quite well discussed in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `trainerLevels` is an array and `currentLevel` is an index.  If so, the way to access an element in an array at a certain index is to use brackets like so.  Otherwise, could you provide more details in your question?

```
var xpForLevel = trainerLevels[currentLevel];
```

If this is the answer that you were looking for, then may I recommend that you use the `parseInt` rather than the `parseFloat` function for getting the index?  And also, since it is user input, you may want to check that `currentLevel` is in the correct range as well.